# Losing session when redirect (node.js + socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a middleware to use socket.io and express together.

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionMiddleWare(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

I send live notification via socket.io, and it's going well. But after using socket.io, and when I redirect to another page i lose my session, in particular session being same for all clients. Before i don't use socket.io all is going good. Even when i redirect to another page i don't lose session. Why i lose session exactly after using socket.io? Help me please.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the shared session part of these [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session)

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = require('express')();
const sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const session = require('express-session')({
  secret: 'my-secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
});
// Share session with io sockets
io.use(sharedsession(session));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still lose session(