# Keep socket connection when new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I have a small project with socket.io and node.js. Basically the landing page (index.html) is a waiting room for players, who can agree to play with each other. In that case, I want to redirect them to a different html (game.html, which is in the same folder as index.html). I want to keep the socket connection, since during the game there has to be communication with the server. I have tried two ways, but both fail. In each case, I change the client-side window.location (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321792/how-to-redirect-a-client-after-a-socket-io-event)).

1) In the javascript file of index.html, I have added an export of the socket object: `export const socket = io();` Then I have imported this object in the other javascript file associated to game.html. But for some reason this doesn't work.

2) I have added another  `const socket = io();` in the javascript file associated to game.html. Then I can use that object. But as expected, this sets up a new connection and the previous connection is lost.

EDIT: I have asked the question also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672050) in the comment. There I learnt that this issue is not really fixable. So I just render game.html inside of index.html (making DOM manipulations in main.js) for now.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119209/losing-session-when-redirect-node-js-socket-io, but I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) writes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672050):

> This is how webSockets and socket.io connections work. They last ONLY
>   for the duration of the page. When you go to a new URL and load a new
>   page, the previous socket.io connection is closed and your code in the
>   new page is free to make a new one. This is how things work in the
>   browser.

Answer (score 0):

Martin, If you re-direct the client to a different endpoint then a new handshake with the server has to be initiated so you will get a new socket.id. What is the information that your server is emitting? Are you able to just re-render the DOM reflecting the new data instead of going to a completely different file? Would React's state management maybe mitigate your problem?

I might be able to help you if you can give me a code example.

Comment: Thanks! The setup is basically that in a waiting room two players agree to play a game. The client-server communication for that is already done and easy. So the users are redirected from the waiting room (index.html) to the actual game (game.html). Yes it is possible to use only one html and render the stuff from game.html in index.html, since in this case the structure is also very similar. But for other projects this won't work. I wonder if really new handshake is necessary when we tell the *server* to redirect the client somewhere (but I don't know the syntax for that).

Comment: I have explained this now also in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass whole Socket to that route as param and there all the socket.io function will work as same as it

```
    const Room=({setSocket})=>{
var socket= useMemo(()=>(io.connect('http://localhost:5000')),[]);
    const value=useMemo(()=>(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000),[])
        socket.code = value
    setSocket(socket)
}
```

in app.is

```
<Route path ='/CreateRoom' element={<CreateRoom setSocket={setSocket}/>}/>
```

using state hook you can import in any route